# Java prepared like statement with an integer

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

My problem, concerning prepared statements in java:

```
SELECT TrackingId FROM table where TrackingId = 5735053
```

TrackingId is an integer column in the database. Whe i change the query to:

```
SELECT TrackingId FROM table where TrackingId = '5735053'
```

it works fine as he converts it automaticly. Same goes to this query:

```
SELECT TrackingId FROM table where TrackingId LIKE '%5735%'
```

This works fine and the database is finding results. In java i want to pass the input value of the user to the query. It works with String and the like statement but not with int:

```
String query = "SELECT AnyString FROM table where AnyString like ?";

connectDatabase();

pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(1, "%"+input+"%");
result = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Now i want to pass an Integer through this statement and i have tried many things but always 0 results. So this won't work:

```
String query = "SELECT AnyInt FROM table where AnyInt like ?";

connectDatabase();

pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(1, "%"+input+"%");
result = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

But if i type the query in my database programm it works fine and he is finding results. Can anybody help me with this here?

Comment: Did you debug to find out what the value of `input` is? This seems correct to me.

Comment: You could try to cast either the field to varchar: `cast(AnyInt as varchar)` or the parameter: `cast(? as varchar)`. I am not 100% sure casting the parameter is supported by SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Your answer is correct. But i found a mistake in my java code and it works also without the cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the field to varchar: `cast(AnyInt as varchar)`. The reason it works as a literal is that then SQL Server knows it is a comparison between int and string and will automatically coerce the int to string. However when you use a parameter, the parameter has the same type as the column: int, so the value `%<somenumber>%` is not a valid value (although I'm surprised that you don't get an exception).

Another option might be to cast the parameter: `cast(? as varchar)`. I am not 100% sure casting the parameter is supported by SQL Server.